# How do I include backticks in an Rstudio code snippet?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm writing a snippet to create the following slide header in a markdown file which is literally as follows:

```
--- .slide  x:`r x("Methods")` y:`r y("Methods")`
```

I want to write a snippet that allows me to type in `Methods` in both fields. The problem is that the backticks are causing the the snippet to be evaluated, not typed.

I'm aware that in this case I could write code that means I don't need the backticks, but I was looking for a way to include backticks in snippets generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sebastian-c You can avoid the warning (for a single expression) by including the entire expression in one quoted string. For example for a snippet that inserts the code for the current date, use

```
`r "\u0060r Sys.Date()\u0060"`
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a verbose way of solving the issue. If you replace all the literal backticks with

```
`r "\u0060"`
```

That causes that snippet to be evaluated which produces a literal backtick. The only catch I've found is that the next time you evaluate something in R (causing warning messages to appear), you'll get:

```
Warning message:
In if (matches == -1) return(snippet) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```